# Gatsbyjs Styled Components CSS delayed loading

Tags: gatsby, styled-components

Currently I am facing a weird issue with GatsbyJS in combination with styled components.

In development everything is working fine but when I built and serve the site locally all styles which are created by styled components are loaded roughly 100 to 300ms later after the page has finished loading. It seems this only applies to styles which are used on layout and template files.

I also included `gatsby-plugin-styled-components` and `babel-plugin-styled-components` into my project without any success.

I created a small demo project at https://github.com/alexanderwe/gatsby-styled-components-test which shows the error. If you want you can download it and run `yarn && yarn workspace gatsby-theme-test serve` to see the error live.

Does anyone experienced a similar issue or has a solution for this ?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you implemented `wrapPageElement` in `gatsby-browser.js`, forgot to implement it in `gatsby-ssr.js` as well. This means styled-components' only activated on browser load, not during server side rendering.

To do this, just copy your `gatsby-browser.js` into a new `gatsby-ssr.js`, the API should be exactly the same.

- [Gatsby SSR API - `wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#wrapPageElement)
- [Gatsby Browser API - `wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#wrapPageElement)

Comment: You are right, I totally forgot about the ssr configuration ... sure if the sites get rendered they do not have the layout applied since it is not the in the gatsby-ssr.js. Thanks a lot, now it works totally fine !